# How to Make an Apex Callout to a REST API via a Proxy Server?

Tags: apex, callout, proxy

I need to make a callout to a REST API from Apex.

This API is accessed via a proxy server - I have the proxy server URL, port, username, and password.

How do I construct my request in Apex such that my callout uses the proxy server?

Most HTTP client libraries and tools like Postman provide a way to specify a proxy to use when making requests.  But I can't find any information on how I would do this for a callout from Apex.

Thanks in advance for your assistance, and please let me know if I can provide any other useful background!

Comment: It depends on the proxy. For many proxies the answer is going to be - no, you can't do this out of the box. You'll need middleware that can talk to the proxy. Some proxies will allow you to call via HTTP with proxy-specific headers and then pass a stripped down version of your request to the destination.

Comment: I ended up creating an intermediary web service in AWS API Gateway/Lambda. I called this web service from Apex (using HMAC for authentication), and then this web service turned around and made the final call to the proxied API, and returned the results.

Comment: It means,, including unnecessary cost.